# SFINAE Template Specialization in Separate Source File

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I am working maintenance on a program with a bunch of different structures that are fundamentally similar.  I want to write a template method that utilizes SFINAE to enable calling this method from the client.  When I define the template specialization inline, everything works as expected.  However, when I try to move the template definition into a separate compilation unit, I run into issues.  I am trying to move the template implementation into a separate file in order to enable using forward declarations for most of the dependent classes.  The following is an example of what I am attempting to achieve:

```
// Impl.h
#pragma once

struct A {
    struct {
        int value;
    } valueA;
};

struct B {
    struct {
        int value;
    } valueB;
};

template<typename T>
int GetValue(T const &value);

// Impl.cpp
#include "Impl.h"
#include <type_traits>

using std::enable_if_t;
using std::remove_reference_t;

template<typename T, typename U, U(T::*Value)>
static inline int GetValueImpl(T const &value) {
    return (value.*Value).value;
}

template<typename T>
enable_if_t<T::valueA, int> GetValue(T const &value) {
    static constexpr auto T::*const Value = &T::valueA;
    typedef remove_reference_t<decltype(value.*Value)> ValueType;
    return GetValueImpl<T, ValueType, Value>(value);
}

template<typename T>
enable_if_t<T::valueB, int> GetValue(T const &value) {
    static constexpr auto T::*const Value = &T::valueB;
    typedef remove_reference_t<decltype(value.*Value)> ValueType;
    return GetValueImpl<T, ValueType, Value>(value);
}

template<> int GetValue(A const &); // C2912 here
template<> int GetValue(B const &); // C2912 here
```

I am using VS2017u2, and am getting error C2912: explicitt specialization 'int GetValue(const A &)' is not a specialization of a function template.  Does anyone know how to make this work with the definitions in a separate compilation unit?

Comment: I guess you are aware of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file , aren't you?

Comment: Nothing about the getvalue template impls requires that A or B be not forward declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `enable_if_t<T::valueA, int>`, it is checking for a static member of `T` called `valueA` (Which would presumably be a `static constexpr bool valueA = /* true or false */;`, like what `T::value` would mean if `T` was `using T = std::is_same<U, V>;` ).

To actually check if it has a member called `valueA` or `valueB`, put it in a context where there would be a substitution error if the member didn't exist, or `true`. Something like:

```
// Pointers to member variables can never be null
// so these will always be enabled if `valueA` or
// `valueB` exist in the first place
enable_if_t<&T::valueA != nullptr, int>
enable_if_t<&T::valueB != nullptr, int>

// But that also allows pointers to static members
// so if you don't want that, you can do something else.
// Like checking if `&T::member` is a pointer to a member
// (But this is probably overkill as you have a specific set
// of types and none of those names are ever static members
// and if you didn't there is a small caveat with
// an overloaded `operator&` but that doesn't really matter)
enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(&T::valueA), decltype(T::valueA) T::*>, int>
enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(&T::valueB), decltype(T::valueB) T::*>, int>
```

Even after fixing the SFINAE check, you are using the wrong syntax for template instantiation. You should use:

```
template int GetValue(A const &);  // No `<>`
template int GetValue(B const &);
```

And after that, it still doesn't work because `template<typename T> enable_if_t<..., int> GetValue(T const&);` and `template<typename T> int GetValue(T const&);` are different functions, so it is ambiguous which one it should instantiate (as both would work). You need to make both of *those* into different functions (`GetValueImpl2` in my example) and have `GetValue` declared the same way as in the header:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include "Impl.h"

using std::enable_if_t;
using std::remove_reference_t;

template<typename T, typename U, U(T::*Value)>
static inline int GetValueImpl(T const &value) {
    return (value.*Value).value;
}

template<typename T>
enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(&T::valueA), decltype(T::valueA) T::*>, int> GetValueImpl2(T const &value) {
    static constexpr auto T::*const Value = &T::valueA;
    using ValueType = decltype(T::valueA);
    return GetValueImpl<T, ValueType, Value>(value);
}

template<typename T>
enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(&T::valueB), decltype(T::valueB) T::*>, int> GetValueImpl2(T const &value) {
    static constexpr auto T::*const Value = &T::valueB;
    using ValueType = decltype(T::valueB);
    return GetValueImpl<T, ValueType, Value>(value);
}

template<typename T>
int GetValue(T const&value) {
    return GetValueImpl2(value);
}


template int GetValue<A>(A const &);
template int GetValue<B>(B const &);
```